# JavaScript DOM selection from HTML string in node.js

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js, dom

I have been working on a single-page JavaScript application where I became dissatisfied with the templating options available, I decided to take a leap and start my own. I did this to not only fulfill my need and to learn, but if someone ends up using it great!

I extracted from my project the functions that I have developed into a working [prototype](https://github.com/msull92/felix) and adhoc solution. At the moment it is based on using a DOM, but I really want/need it to work on my node.js side as well. So the hope is that someone can check out the repo and point me in the right direction on how to adapt this solution to using strings instead of DOM elements. Yes, I do understand that it will probably require a complete rewrite.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hopefully you've seen [this template engine choice assistant](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/). Personally I'm a big fan of [doT.js](http://olado.github.io/doT/) because it's tiny, fast, extremely flexible, and works purely with strings.

Comment: Yes, I have. Again, this is mostly about learning to dyi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) on the node side as it provides some DOM basics as well as some DOM traversal and manipulation compatible with portions of the jQuery API.

Comment: Awesome! This will work great with what I already have going. Thank you for not telling me to just use a different templating library!

Comment: FYI I have been using it extensively and have not hit a single problem thus far.